# Relative Date from Unix Timestamp with PHP

Tags: php

I've seen a few other people talking about relative dates, but I still haven't managed to get it working properly.

My script pulls a unix timestamp from a MySQL database and I would like the it to display something like this:

> 2 minutes ago
>   16 hours ago
>   On Tuesday 10th November at 7pm

Thanks to anyone who can help.

Comment: You aren't asking an actual technical question, nor are you posting source code for people to identify flaws and help you fix it.

Comment: I did search - but I could only find answers that were not relevant to my predicament. There was one to do with a datetime in ASP.NET, but that is not what I am asking for. There was another one to do with datetime, but again I am dealing with UNIX timestamps.

I was also not necessarily asking someone to write a function for me, just if anyone had come across one that would fit somewhere else or if they had previously written one for another project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's probably a better way to do it, but here's a rough function I wrote ages ago for this:

```
function time_ago($datetime)
{
    if (is_numeric($datetime)) {
      $timestamp = $datetime;
    } else {
      $timestamp = strtotime($datetime);
    }
    $diff=time()-$timestamp;

    $min=60;
    $hour=60*60;
    $day=60*60*24;
    $month=$day*30;

    if($diff<60) //Under a min
    {
        $timeago = $diff . " seconds";
    }elseif ($diff<$hour) //Under an hour
    {
        $timeago = round($diff/$min) . " mins";
    }elseif ($diff<$day) //Under a day
    {
        $timeago = round($diff/$hour) . " hours";
    }elseif ($diff<$month) //Under a day
    {
        $timeago = round($diff/$day) . " days";
    }else 
    {
        $timeago = round($diff/$month) ." months";
    }

    return $timeago;

}
```

Comment: Does this take in a datetime (00:00 00 00 ish) or a UNIX timestamp (1322061969)?

If it takes in a datetime, how do I convert a timestamp to it?

Comment: It takes a datetime. I've updated my answer to show how it'd look if you wanted to pass in a unix timestamp instead

Comment: No worries, as I said, it's not the greatest of functions, but it'll work for simple things. It doesn't take into account daylight savings, and the $min/$hour/$day/$month variables should have probably been set explicitly instead of getting PHP to work them out, but that shouldn't be a big overhead on the server so I guess it's not a major issue.

Answer (score 1):

I just wrote a simple function today,
for your reference :-

```
/* calculate simple human readable time format */
function simple_human_date($from, $to)
{
$diff  = $to - $from;
$range = array
(   
    'year'  => 31536000,
    'month' => 2592000,
    'day'   => 86400,
    'week'  => 604800,
    'hour'  => 3600,
    'min'   => 60
);  

foreach ($range as $unit=>$sec)
{   
    if ($diff > $sec)
    {
       $round = round($diff/$sec);
       break;
    }
}   

if (empty($round))
{   
    return 'just now';
}   
else
{   
    return sprintf('%d %s%s ago', $round, $unit, $round>1?'s':'');
}   
}
```

NOTE: the idea is to assemble something like this :- http://youlookfab.com/welookfab/

Comment: Except that there aren't always 31536000 seconds in a year.  And there aren't always 86400 seconds in a day.  Please don't re-invent date math.  It's a lot harder than you think.  There's a lot you need to keep track of (daylight savings time, leap seconds, leap years, etc)...

Comment: well ... is meant for simple usage (as per function say), plus more than 50% people stay in area don't have DST :)

Answer (score 1):

In PHP 5.3.0+

Example:

```
$d1 = new DateTime();
$d2 = new DateTime();
$d2->modify('-1 day');
echo $d2->diff($d1)->format('%d') ' day';
```

See also 
http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php 
http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php

Answer (score 0):

That's usually done with a bit of client-side logic to determine what granularity to display the time string with. Assuming your query returns unix-style timestamps:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(now()), blog_post_timestamp FROM ...
```

You'll get (using made-up numbers): `1234 900` for your two time values. So the time difference is 334 seconds (1234-900), and you'd process it:

```
if (time_difference < 60) {
   $time_display = "Posted $time_difference seconds ago";
} if ((time_difference >= 60) AND (time_difference < 3600)) {
   $minutes = ceil($time_difference / 60);
   $time_display = "Posted $minutes minutes ago";
} else {
   $hours = ceil($time_difference / 3600);
   $time_display = "Posted $hours hours ago";
}
```

and you just keep adding more time units as you want: days, weeks, months, years, centuries, etc...