# PHP: Minutes to year month day hour minute

Tags: php, math, time

I'm making a text based PHP game. Every second there is an update, and update, the row `time` gets selected from the database, containing for example `548991`. That means `548991` minutes have gone by, so that means that for example its the first year, the first month, the 4th day, the 7th hour and the 51th minute. How can i calculate that, so that the number 548991 results into: **Year 1, Month 1, Day 4, 07:51 AM** using PHP code?

Comment: you are supposed to use the search function before asking. How to format a timestamp and a date to relative time has been answered multiple times before and I take you are smart enough to convert seconds to minutes on your own.

Comment: @Gordon I did search, i'm not new to Stackoverflow and i know the rules, but mathematical questions are not my best side, i've been stuck on this for a few hours now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Relative Date from Unix Timestamp with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8244642/relative-date-from-unix-timestamp-with-php)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=relative+time+php

Comment: @Gordon Still haven't found my solution between those.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Time Since Function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5010016/php-time-since-function)

Comment: The point is that you need to convert your value in minutes to seconds in order to have a unix timestamp, which will let you use all of the time family of functions (just multiply your minutes value by 60 and take a look in any of the references offered by the others).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alot of extra effort is spent not answering this question. Also, Thew, I know you didn't give up, so answering your own question when you find a solution would have been good for your Karma.

My grandfather once told me you catch more flies with honey. I get what these guys are saying, but I just think we should all treat each other a little better.

Answering with some tags...

[format](/questions/tagged/format) [date-diff](/questions/tagged/date-diff)

Answering with some code...

```php
$datetime1 = new DateTime('now - {$minutes}minutes');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('now');
$interval = date_diff($datetime2,$datetime1);
echo $interval->format('%r Year %y, Month %m, Day %d, %H:%I %a');
```

Answering removes this question from the unanswered list...

Peace

Comment: Ever thought of becoming a teacher? You are simply awesome. All the kids at school will love you.